# How do I realistically create cracks and scratches in object?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, photorealism

I'm working on this project, in which I'm trying to re-create a photo in Blender.

I used FSpy to capture vanishing points to create the scene, but I stumbled upon a problem. The marks and scratches in the wall are really hard to re-create for me. I tried to look up some tutorials, and did it procedurally, but it didn't look accurate.

Whenever I tried to sculpt, the wall would for some reason go darker, which really ruins the emersion.

Please help! I would love to know how to get around this and create these details.

**Image I am referring to:**

[image]

**Render I have currently:**

[image]

**Example of wall getting darker once sculpted:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to mix a scratch texture with your wall texture?

Comment: I'm trying to aim for a really accurate render, and the scratch textures I've tried to use weren't really good. Maybe I'm just bad at finding good textures, who knows. -edit I don't know any good texture websites for blender that aren't limited in amount or quality

Comment: Hi :). Check our local [list of texture resources](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15358/78972). I'm sure you'll find what you need there.

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks alot, I'll look into this.